# Wordpress: How to add referral variable on wp_nav_menu link

Tags: wordpress, menu

I need help!

wp_nav_menu() creates an html output

```
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=1">home</a></li>
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=2">news</a></li>
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=3">reviews</a></li>
```

how am I going to add a referral variable to the link? like these:

```
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=1&ref=abc">home</a></li>
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=2&ref=mno">news</a></li>
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=3&ref=xyz">reviews</a></li>
```

any help will be appreciated.

**Update**: 
   I have to get the literal name (home, news and reviews) like this:

```
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=1&ref=home">home</a></li>
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=2&ref=news">news</a></li>
<li id="xxx" class="xxx"><a  href="http://localhost/?page_id=3&ref=reviews">reviews</a></li>
```

it will be used as the category name.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the nav menu output in your `functions.php`:

```
function add_ref_value( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // check some value in the $item object and generate ref value
    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'add_ref_value', null, 3 );
```

**Update:** Actually, I think you'd be better off using this method: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

This should make it much easier to generate and append your `ref` attribute.

Here are a few more links to help you:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L10 - The nav menu walker class in the WP source code
- http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/ - in depth description of the walker class

Comment: here's what's in my function.php

<?php if (function_exists('register_nav_menus')){
  register_nav_menus(array('topmenu' => __('Top Menu')));
         }
?>

I'm new to wordpress and php but i'll try to figure this out. thanks.

Comment: No problem, the first link is specific to your case but the tutsplus link has an excellent description of the walker class in general if things get confusing.

Comment: You are one of the people that makes the internet so awesome. thank you very much @Joe

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! I edited nav-menu-template.php at line 86.

```
$attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )? ' href="'. esc_attr( $item->url) .'&ref=' .$item->title. '"' : '';
```

I added the &ref=' .$item->title. '

this might help others especially if they want to fetch variable from the url.

I want to learn walker class though.... thanks again @joe